# Is this SQL query, injection safe

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-injection

I think the initial code is fine:

```
SqlCommand param = new SqlCommand();
SqlGeometry point = SqlGeometry.Point(center_lat,center_lng,0);
SqlGeometry poly = SqlGeometry.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(new SqlString(polygon)),0);
param.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Circle (Center_Point, Circle_Data) VALUES (@point,@poly);";
param.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@point", SqlDbType.Udt));
param.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@poly", SqlDbType.Udt));
param.Parameters["@point"].UdtTypeName = "geometry";
param.Parameters["@poly"].UdtTypeName = "geometry";
param.Parameters["@point"].Value = point;
param.Parameters["@poly"].Value = poly;
```

However I realised there could be a problem when the `polygon` string is created.

in javascript - I create it like so:

```
var Circle_Data = "POLYGON ((";
for (var x = 0; x < pointsToSql.length; x++) { // formatting = 0 0, 150 0, 150 50 etc
    if (x == 360) { Circle_Data += pointsToSql[x].lat.toString() + " " + pointsToSql[x].lng.toString() + "))"; }
    else { Circle_Data += pointsToSql[x].lat.toString() + " " + pointsToSql[x].lng.toString() + ","; }
}
```

It is then passed to C#. So is this safe? even though the parametrization has happened in the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the parameter you will be saved from SQL Injection, If some SQL is injected in the `POLYGON` string, it will error out at SQL Server end.

So for example if you have :

```
POLYGON(12.33 12.55,13.55; DROP TABLE students;)
```

SQL server will try to construct a geometry type based on the passed string, and it will fail doing so.